# Can't disable password on Android 6.0 (EMUI 4.0)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, lock-screens, huawei

I had to go somewhere and due to my paranoia, I decided to lock my Huawei P8 Lite. Since that day I can't disable the password beacuse I always get this note `Disabled by administrator, encryption policy, or credential storage`

The only Device administrator is Google's Find my phone, which I deactivated and is not the problem (so I switched it back), I cleared all credentials from Security, I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: I removed my SD, I have no VPNs..

Comment: OK here is the trick, first you did right by clearing credentials, next reboot your device (important), then again clear the credentials, the options should now be visible

Comment: @xavier_fakerat nope, ain't working

Comment: See: https://forums.androidcentral.com/huawei-p8/593567-how-do-i-disable-screen-lock-my-p8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [xavier_fakerat's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180860/cant-disable-password-on-android-6-0-emui-4-0/180874#comment232737_180860) that mentioned [Android Central Forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/huawei-p8/593567-how-do-i-disable-screen-lock-my-p8.html). You need to do this:

1. Set up a pattern password with a backup PIN
2. Double-tap the power button to activate the lock screen
3. Do wrong patterns 5 times (at least 4 dots touched to be counted as an attempt), then wait for the cooldown
4. Select backup PIN, enter your PIN and you could select "none"

Answer (score 1):

The accepted [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180874/96277) did not work for my Android 5.1 version. This is what worked:

1. Go to **Settings** → tap **Security** → clear all credentials.
2. Go back to **Screen lock**. The option NONE will be available. You can then remove the screen lock.